# How to clean or flush cache programmatically in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cache

I have tried DI and Object Manager way to clean or flush cache but its not working for me

**using DI**

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
    $this->_cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
}
$types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
foreach ($types as $type) {
    $this->_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
}
foreach ($this->_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
    $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
}
```

**using ObjectManager:**

```
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$indexerCollectionFactory = $obj->get("\Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory");
$indexerFactory = $obj->get("\Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory");

// custom function for reindexing
public function reIndexing(){
    $indexerCollection = $indexerCollectionFactory->create();
    $allIds = $indexerCollection->getAllIds();

    foreach ($allIds as $id) {
        $indexer = $indexerFactory->create()->load($id);
        //$indexer->reindexRow($id); // or you can use reindexRow according to your need
        $indexer->reindexAll(); // this reindexes all
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically i am calling a block function when a product detail page is open and in block function i am using the above code which not flush cache for me .One way is that i use cacheable false its working for me but it disable the cache for all page anywhere the block is call .so i am finding a way in which there is no need of doing cacheable false for block

Comment: Can you please tell me why do you want to clear cache in product detail page ?

Comment: @MuzammalHassan bacially i am working on extention development and there i want to display product view count .so i need to clear cache to increment the view whenever the page is requested

Comment: Are you saving view count in the database ? or you getting view count on run time?

Answer (score 1):

Hard coding the types is a bad idea. Instead you can use the same method used by the cache:flush and cache:clean commands. The cache manager class can also pull all the cache types for you, as done in the example below.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Manager $cacheManager
) {
    $this->cacheManager = $cacheManager;
}

private function whereYouNeedToCleanCache()
{
    $this->cacheManager->flush($this->cacheManager->getAvailableTypes());

    // or this
    $this->cacheManager->clean($this->cacheManager->getAvailableTypes());
}
```

Comment: i have tried this before but its also not working

Comment: did you try this ? https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-clean-and-flush-cache-programmatically-in-magento2/

Comment: yes i have tried

Comment: both one is working well !!!

Comment: <?php
    $command = 'php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush';
    echo '<pre>' . shell_exec($command) . '</pre>';
?>

Comment: above pasted code of DI way is same as provided on link

Comment: please try the core commands using shell_exec

Comment: by using command on terminal cache is flush but i want to do it using code

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-clear-or-flush-cache-programmatically-in-magento-2/